# Always asks to install or try?

Tags: installation, boot, flash, drive

I already installed Ubuntu on my computer, but every time it starts to boot, it asks if I want to try Ubuntu or install.  Do I still need the flash drive containing Ubuntu plugged in (it currently is)?

Comment: After the installation has finished, it will prompt you to remove the installation media... So no, you should remove it as instructed.

Answer (score 2):

After the installation completed you may have not seen this message:

[image]

This tells you to remove the CD or USB from where you had installed Ubuntu. Otherwise, and in case you still have set your BIOS to boot from CD/USB, you will boot from the installation CD/USB and not from your hard drive.